# passing argument 1 of " " from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I have three warnings on my program.

First:

> ```
> passing argument 1 of " " from incompatible pointer type at line 18 and assigment makes integer from pointer without a cast at line 37
> ```

Here is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>


struct Equipo {
   char nombre [20];
   int goles[7];
};
struct Equipo resultados [6];

void LeerFich(struct Equipo *resultados);

void main()
{
    struct Equipo *equipos;
    LeerFich(&equipos);    //warning here
    Buscar(equipos);
    MarcaCero(equipos);
}

//Funciones

void LeerFich(struct Equipo *resultados)
{
    FILE *F;
    F= fopen("C:\\Users\\Paco\\Downloads\\datosLiga.txt", "r");
    fgets(resultados->nombre, 20, F);
    fscanf(F, "%d", &resultados->goles);
    fclose(F);
}
int Buscar(struct Equipo resultados[6], int v[6])
{
    int i, *maximo, sum, *equipo, t=6;
    for(i=0; i<6; i++){
        sum += resultados[i].goles;      //warning here
        if(resultados[i].goles>maximo)
            maximo=resultados[i].goles;
            *equipo=i;
    }
    while(i<t && v[i]!=*equipo)
        i++;
    if(i==t)
        printf("el equipo es: %s\n", resultados[*equipo].nombre);
        printf("ha marcado %d goles\n", *maximo);
}
int MarcaCero(struct Equipo resultados[6])
{
    int i, v[6];
    for(i=0; i<6; i++){
        if(resultados[i].goles[0]==0 && resultados[i].goles[7]==0)
            i=v[i];
    }
    for(i=0; i<6; i++)
        printf("\nel equipo %s no marco", resultados[v[i]].nombre);
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Replace

```
LeerFich(&equipos);    //warning here
```

by

```
LeerFich(equipos);
```

`equipos` is already of type `struct Equipo *`, there is no need to take its address.

Comment: Also note that `equipos` is used in `LeerFich` (as `resultados`) without being allocated.

Comment: Thank you but i have one more warning, can you solve the other warning? Thank you, much appreciate :D

Comment: @ouah Why isn't this treated as error instead of a warnign?

Comment: @Danijel Compiler choice to be permissive. C requires the diagnostic, it does not require stopping the translation.

Answer (score 1):

```
LeerFich(&equipos);
```

here you are sending the address of the pointer variable which can not be received by the declaration

Use : `LeerFich(equipos);`